# Java Jackson Always Serialize One Type As Another

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, jackson

Is there a way to tell Jackson to always serialize one type to another. In my case I would like to always serialize Long to String. Right now whenever there is an object with a Long property we have to annotate it with `@JsonSerialize(using=ToStringSerializer.class)`. This is tedious and easy to forget.

I would like to be able to configure the Jackson object mapper to always convert Long to String in the spring boot bean creation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*IMHO, multiple options are there.*

**I**

com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.StdSerializer implementation that can be set to your ObjectMapper in the spring context.

```
    @Bean
    public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder objectMapperBuilder() {
        Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder = new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder();
        ....
        builder.serializerByType(<type>, <your custom serializer>);
        return builder;
    }
```

As for the custom serializer, you can extend the above-mentioned class `StdSerializer`.

**II**

spring.jackson.generator.write-numbers-as-strings=true

**Note**

Be aware of that Feature.WRITE_NUMBERS_AS_STRINGS has deprecated Since 2.10 of jackson version.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks! That's a really clean solution. For my use case I was able to simply use the pre-made ToStringSerializer that jackson provides.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using this serialization feature.

```
jsonGenerator.configure(Feature.WRITE_NUMBERS_AS_STRINGS,true);
```

http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-core/javadoc/2.10/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/json/JsonWriteFeature.html#WRITE_NUMBERS_AS_STRINGS

Comment: Will this convert all numbers including ints? I only want to serialize Longs as Strings. This does solve the problem though.
Edit: Read documentation which confirms it will convert all numbers to string.